# The open in new tab links are not open in the new tab

Tags: bug, profile-page, hyperlinks

The open in new tab links of **Newsletters** and **Question Subscriptions** in the site's [**Edit Profile & Settings**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/edit/current) under the **EMAIL SETTINGS** are not open in the new tab, instead of it opens in the same page.

This issue exists in all the Stack Exchange sites.

[image]

Comment: What made you think the icons mean "open in new tab"? It's not written anywhere. I have no idea what they mean, they are just noise for me, guess they might mean "this points to some other site", due to the arrow pointing out.

Answer (score 2):

The icon doesn't mean the links will open in a new tab. It means the links point to a different domain than the one you're currently on.

When clicking on those links, you are leaving `meta.stackexchange.com` and navigating to `stackexchange.com`.

Comment: They why the link in the [Create job alert](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/job-alerts/current) opens in new tab?

Comment: @Arulkumar No idea. There's a lot of theory on when to open a new tab/window and when not to. But the icon doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: @Arulkumar there is no policy. Every developer decides on his/her own how the link will behave when adding new links. That's the way it always was in SE, and most likely always will be. (And that's why it's a total mess, some links open in new tab, some same window, etc.)